# Show a query to edit all values of an array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I create a formular to edit the value for each invoices.items -> item_name using AngularJS?

```
invoices: {
_id: "78327837"
name: "ajay"
invoice_no: "23"
items: [
 0: {
item_name: "nasm"
quantity: "god"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="item in invoice.items" ng-model="item.item_name">
```

Comment: using this code it show empty form